# Google sitemaps: Url is not allowed at this location

Tags: google, sitemap

Hi I have made a sitemap for my website. I went to google search console and added my sitemap.xml when I click test it displays the details and says that all 8 URL's are not allowed? what have I done wrong and how do I fix it? I am using GoDaddy for a domain and googledrive for hosting. Here is the xml sitemap file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset
      xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9
            http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd">
<!-- created with Free Online Sitemap Generator www.xml-sitemaps.com -->




<url>
  <loc>https://bb5d0a86491f4067116947906654255edf209f12.googledrive.com/host/0B5JL3GH0xtHPcHdmd05kRUVsWms/</loc>
  <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
</url>
<url>
  <loc>https://bb5d0a86491f4067116947906654255edf209f12.googledrive.com/host/0B5JL3GH0xtHPcHdmd05kRUVsWms/news.html</loc>
  <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
</url>
</urlset>
```

Comment: Every URL within your sitemap MUST be on your domain and not another domain.

Answer (score 1):

As @closetnoc said every URL in the sitemap must be under your domain otherwise anyone could claim that the Google homepage belongs to them simply by adding it to their sitemap.xml file.

Source: http://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html